# Erlang driver erl_errno issue

Tags: erlang, erlang-driver

I am playing with `erl_driver`. Start callback of my driver is below:

`ErlDrvData drv_start(ErlDrvPort port, char* command) {
    char* file_name = command + sizeof(drv_name);
    GenTtyData* port_data = (GenTtyData*)driver_alloc(sizeof(GenTtyData));
    erl_errno = gt_open(file_name, &port_data->file);
    if (erl_errno != 0) {
        // Assertion there is just to show you my intention
        assert(erl_errno == ENOENT); 
        driver_free(port_data);
        return ERL_DRV_ERROR_ERRNO;
    }
    return port_data;
}`

[Documentation says](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/driver_entry.html)

ErlDrvData (*start)(ErlDrvPort port, char* command)

```
This is called when the driver is instantiated, when open_port/2 is called. The driver should return a number >= 0 or a pointer, or if the driver can't be started, one of three error codes should be returned:

ERL_DRV_ERROR_GENERAL - general error, no error code

ERL_DRV_ERROR_ERRNO - error with error code in erl_errno

ERL_DRV_ERROR_BADARG - error, badarg

If an error code is returned, the port isn't started.
```

So I expect that `erlang:open_port/2` will send exit signal containing error description (`eacces` for example, or `enotty`). However, in test I have

`{'EXIT',
    {unknown,
        [{erlang,open_port,[{spawn,"gen_tty_drv non_existent.tty"},[]],[]},
         {gen_tty,open,1,
             [{file,
                  "/home/vkovalev/workspace/gen_tty_drv/_build/test/lib/gen_tty/src/gen_tty.erl"},
              {line,48}]},
         {gen_tty_drv_SUITE,open_non_existent_file,1,
             [{file,
                  "/home/vkovalev/workspace/gen_tty_drv/test/gen_tty_drv_SUITE.erl"},
              {line,29}]},
         {test_server,ts_tc,3,[{file,"test_server.erl"},{line,1450}]},
         {test_server,run_test_case_eval1,6,
             [{file,"test_server.erl"},{line,1026}]},
         {test_server,run_test_case_eval,9,
             [{file,"test_server.erl"},{line,968}]}]}}`

It seems erlang doesn't see or can't decode error reason and sends `unknown`. So what's wrong with my `start` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug either in the documentation or the code. If the code that invokes the driver `start` function finds that the function returns `ERL_DRV_ERROR_ERRNO`, [it takes the error number from `errno`, not `erl_errno`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/io.c#L709) (*this is true as of otp master commit dc35ae6c, anyway, which is roughly Erlang version 18.0-rc2; you might find it's different in later versions*).

To prove this, I wrote a driver `start` function that sets `errno` explicitly:

```
static ErlDrvData
my_driver_start(ErlDrvPort port, char *command)
{
    errno = ETXTBSY;
    return ERL_DRV_ERROR_ERRNO;
}
```

and with this approach, I got the result you're seeking:

```
1> my_driver:start().
** exception error: etxtbsy
     in function  open_port/2
        called as open_port({spawn,my_driver},[binary])
     in call from my_driver:start/0 (my_driver.erl, line 10)
```

Setting `erl_errno` in the same manner, though, did not produce this result. If I explicitly set `errno` to a garbage value and then set `erl_errno` to a valid error number, like this:

```
static ErlDrvData
my_driver_start(ErlDrvPort port, char *command)
{
    errno = 3245690989;
    erl_errno = ETXTBSY;
    return ERL_DRV_ERROR_ERRNO;
}
```

then I get the same `unknown` result as you:

```
1> my_driver:start().
** exception error: unknown
     in function  open_port/2
        called as open_port({spawn,my_driver},[binary])
     in call from my_driver:start/0 (my_driver.erl, line 10)
```

*Update: I contacted a member of the OTP team about this and they replied by email that this is a documentation bug, which means using `errno` rather than `erl_errno` is the right solution. They said this part of the driver code has always used `errno`.*

*Update 2: This issue has been fixed in the [`driver_entry` documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/driver_entry.html) as of Erlang 18.0.*

Comment: Exactly! That's it. Great thanks for link to `beam/io.c`. I was not able to find this code by myself.